# Problem while using scanf("%19[^\n]",Input) in C

Tags: c

So basically when I use scanf("%19[^\n]", Input); I get a problem in my output  .

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void inputTime();

    int main()
    {
        int test = 0;
       do
       {
         inputTime();
         test++;
       } while (test!=2);

       return 0;
    }
    void inputTime()
    {

       char Input[20];
         printf("Test : ");
          *Input = '\0';
          scanf("%19[^\n]", Input);
    }
```

After the first input of my char[] , the program and exactly the [^\n] can't let me output twice .
This is what I get in my output:

```
Test : SomeString
Test :                        //Not capable to input a second string
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 11.599 s
Press any key to continue.
```

However if I change scanf("%19[^\n]", Input) to scanf("%19s", Input) it works correctly

```
Test : SomeString
Test : AnotherString                     //Writing here is now possible 
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 11.599 s
Press any key to continue.
```

How can I get the same result while using  scanf("%19[^\n]", Input)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "*After the first input of my char[] , the program and exactly the [^\n] can't let me output twice. However if I change `scanf("%19[^\n]", Input)` to `scanf("%19s", Input)` it works correctly.*"

This is because the `%[` conversion specifier in:

```
scanf("%19[^\n]", Input);
```

contrary to the conversion specifier `%s`, does not skip leading white space characters such as the `\n` (newline) made by the press to `Return` left in `stdin` from the previous call to it in the previous iteration of the loop in `main`.

Either add a white space character directive before `%[`:

```
scanf(" %19[^\n]", Input);
```

or insert a `getchar()` call before to catch the left `newline`.